# How to pass data to console app and handle it's output?

Tags: d

I have got console app that get parameters to start and then output result of calculation.

Example (from [docs](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html)):

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:31370
```

> 177502 311865

In step-by step mode it's work like:

1. `gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:31370` [press enter]
2. I input from keyboard: `177502 311865` [press enter]
3. it's print on screen new coordinates: `244296.723070577 165937.350438393 1.60975147597492`

I need to call it's from D, pass input parametrs, and handle it's output.

It's seems that I need use [pipeShell](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html#.pipeShell) for it, but I can't understand how to use it.

Here is my code:

```d
import std.stdio;
import std.process;
import std.file;

void main()
{
    auto pipes = pipeProcess(["gdaltransform", " -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857"], Redirect.stdout);
    scope(exit) wait(pipes.pid);
}
```

But how to read of `gdaltransform` output to variable and then terminate app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
import std.stdio;
import std.process;

void main() {
    // spawn child process by pipeProcess
    auto pipes = pipeProcess(["gdaltransform", "-s_srs", "EPSG:28992", "-t_srs", "EPSG:31370"], Redirect.all);

    // or by pipeShell
    //auto pipes = pipeShell("gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:31370", Redirect.all);

    scope(exit) {
        // send terminate signal to the child process
        kill(pipes.pid);
        // waiting for terminate
        wait(pipes.pid);
    }

    // write data to child's stdin
    pipes.stdin.writeln("177502, 311865");

    // close child's stdin
    pipes.stdin.close();

    // read data from child's stdout
    string line = pipes.stdout.readln();

    write("result: ", line);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you call `close`? Maybe `flush` will be sufficient?

Comment: `flush` should be sufficient, but on my CentOS 7 it shouldn't. I don't know why. Maybe `gdaltransform` doesn't flush its stdio